# Including ffmpeg in Django project

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

I am making a very simple Django app (it's a test for non-Django course) and I need to analyse a mp3 file in there, so I try to turn it into wav with this:

```
 sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3('upload/' + filename)
 sound.export('upload/wavfile', format="wav")
 rate, data = wav.read('upload/wavfile')
```

I have installed ffmpeg by `pip install ffmpeg` in venv terminal, since I want to my code to run not only on my machine. The **ffmpeg** and **ffprobe** folders have appeared in /venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ however when I run my server I get the warning:

> RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg,
>   but may not work
>        warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

and when I load file in web page it throws

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'

at the first line of the code above.

I would really appreciate any help with how I can use ffmpeg in my app or other ways to handle my mp3 file.

Comment: In addition to the Python ffmpeg bindings have you installed `ffmpeg` (the actual program)?

Comment: ah yes thank you, now it has came to my attention that i didn't install the actual app in my system, now I have and it is working correctly. 
however it means that it won't run on a someone else machine and this is what concerns me

Answer (score 0):

You have to add path for ffmpeg executable

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/ffmpeg')

or 

import ffmpy

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(executable='C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', inputs={path+'/Stage1Rap.wav': None}, outputs={path+'/FinalRap.mp3': ["-filter:a", "atempo=0.5"]})
ff.run()
```